# How to convert dataframe rows into json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON structure:
[image]

I'm trying to apply some functions but it tells me that:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iterrows'`.

So, I decided to convert it into JSON for each data frame row.

I tried the following code:

```
for i in data.index:
    data = data.loc[i].to_json("row{}.json".format(i))
```

But it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: There seems to be a discrepency between the screenshot and the rest of your question: Both together don't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data is NoneType (Empty).

Usually, iterrows will be sufficient here.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index)
```

The issue could be in `read_json()` check your data with `df.head()`

Comment: Correct! It shows empty indexes. What should I do then?

Comment: you need to read the data properly.. check the source file